# scala how to access to element in tuple in list

Tags: list, scala

I have a list where two element are tuple. 
How can I access to the elements of the tuple?

```
package prova_package

object prova_worksheet {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       //> Welcome to the Scala worksheet
  var l = List((1,'a'),(2,'b'),3,4)               //> l  : List[Any] = List((1,a), (2,b), 3, 4)
    var u = (1,'a')                           //> u  : (Int, Char) = (1,a)
    u._1                                      //> res0: Int = 1
 //l(1)._1  //this does not work. Why?  How can I access to the value 'b' ?


}
```

I want the value 'b'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Scala is a static language**.

Your code does not work because you've mixed different types for elements. That's why the compiler infers a type `List[Any]` for your list. Your code would have worked fine if the list had a type `List[(Int, Char)]`.

While there is a way to work around your issue using casting I want to outline boldly that it is unidiomatic:

```
l(1).asInstanceOf[(Int, Char)]._1
```

An idiomatic approach is to have monomorphic lists, i.e., the ones containing elements of the same type.

Comment: Last question:  what if I want to modify an element in a List([Int,Char]) ?

Comment: In idiomatic Scala, you would create a new list with a replacement for the item you want to edit. Usually, you want to edit all of the items, with some sort of criteria. That's when `map` and friends are useful. You may want to post your specific problem as a question, because the best method of achieving your edit will depend on the exact situation.